# SQL Query across multiple SQL servers

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-list

I have 2 SQL servers. I need a SQL query that can join 2 tables that are in two different server.

Like

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Server1.Db1.dbo.table1 A
        INNER JOIN Server2.Db1.dbo.table2 B ON A.Id = B.Id
```

and I do not have the server names, instead I am using IP address of the servers. Do I need to enable these SQL servers as linked server to allow such cross server queries?

Comment: If these databases are on different servers then yes you need to create a linked server for this.

Comment: You can use linked servers or OPENDATASOURCE. Be careful, these remote queries can get out of hand quickly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-server SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70455/cross-server-sql)

Comment: There is a post called:  "Selecting data from two different servers in SQL Server" here in StackOverflow --> http://stackoverflow.com/q/1144051/771579

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can proceed with Linked Servers using `sp_addlinkedserver`.
Once done, you can query your data as you mentioned;

```
SELECT  *
FROM    [Db1].[dbo].table1 A
INNER JOIN [Server2].[Db1].[dbo].table2 B 
ON A.Id = B.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, add as linker server is one option. You also can join the remote table by use [ip address].dbname.dbo.table name s well.

Comment: With IP address it still needs to be in sys.servers (MS SQL 2012).